# What does this intention with lots of numbers mean in a SSL certificate?

Tags: permissions, ssl-certificate, certificate

I was looking at [this site](https://www.verisign.com/repository/root.html), and out of interest, I was having a look at the certificate in Chrome 32, on Windows 8.1, and I had a look at the certificate.

I saw this really strange intention, Apart from the usual:

> Ensures the identity of a remote computer
>
> Proves your identity to a remote computer

I saw this one too:

> 2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.23.6

[image]

What is this intention/permission for, and what does it do?

Comment: http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.23.6.html

Comment: So, its a unique ID for Verisign?

Comment: yes...you are correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is an [OID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier), not random numbers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate

According to wikipedia:

> Extended Validation certificate identification
>
> EV certificates are standard x.509 digital certificates. The primary
>   way to identify an EV certificate is by referencing the Certificate
>   Policies extension field. Each issuer uses a different object
>   identifier (OID) in this field to identify their EV certificates, and
>   each OID is documented in the issuer's Certification Practice
>   Statement. As with root certificate authorities in general, browsers
>   may not recognize all issuers.

In the case of this OID:

> VeriSign  2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.23.6  VeriSign EV CPS v. 3.3, p. 87

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. So is this just like a unique ID for the company/site that is vending/issuing the certificate? Sorry, but I don't really know much about certificates!

Comment: Yes, these ID's are typically identified by validation software (probably hardcoded, but dont know) as a means to identify it as a EV certificate rather than a standard certificate.